# Aggregations on nested fields in Elasticsearch transform

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl

Using elasticsearch-dsl, I have created a document ProductCategory which contains a nested field products, with innerdoc Products, as shown below:

```py
class ProductCategory(Document):
        category_id = Integer(required=True)
        products = Nested(Products, multi=True)
        date = Date(required=True)
    
    
class Products(InnerDoc):
    """
    Class used to represent a denormalized user stored on other objects.
    """

    product_id = Integer(multi=True)
    category_position = Integer(multi=True)
```

Given this document I want to apply a transform in which I apply an aggregation on the nested field, see the following code:

```json
{
  "source": {
    "index": ["category_index"],
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {
            "range": {
              "date": {
                "gte": "now-365d",
                "lte": "now"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "category_transformation"
  },
  "sync": {
    "time": {
      "field": "date",
      "delay": "1h"
    }
  },
  "pivot": {
    "group_by": {
      "category_id": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "category_id"
        }
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "related_product_info": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "products"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "product_info": {
            "filter": {
              "range": {
                "products.category_position": {
                  "gte": 1,
                  "lte": 6000
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the above code, I receive the following error: **Validation Failed: 1: Unsupported aggregation type [nested]**. For this reason, I applied a work-around, in which I add an aggration around the nested-field aggregation, as shown in the code below:

```json
{
  "source": {
    "index": ["category_index"],
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {
            "range": {
              "date": {
                "gte": "now-365d",
                "lte": "now"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "category_transformation"
  },
  "sync": {
    "time": {
      "field": "date",
      "delay": "1h"
    }
  },
  "pivot": {
    "group_by": {
      "category_id": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "category_id"
        }
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "nested_category_info": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "category_id",
          "size": 1
        },
        "aggs": {
          "related_product_info": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "products"
            },
            "aggs": {
              "product_info": {
                "filter": {
                  "range": {
                    "products.category_position": {
                      "gte": 1,
                      "lte": 6000
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To me this above code seems to work. Therefore, I was wondering whether this procedure is correct, and if not, what other procedure can be used in order to apply an aggregation on a nested field when using a transform in elastic search.

I would like to thank you in advance.